# How to run tuckarm on Hydro?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know the instruction on groovy:

```
rosrun pr2_tuckarm tuck_arms.py -r t -l t -q
```

It shows:

```
ira@ira:/opt/ros/hydro$ rosrun pr2_tuckarm tuck_arms.py -r t -l t -q
[rospack] Error: stack/package pr2_tuckarm not found
ira@ira:/opt/ros/hydro$
```

How to run it on Hydro?

Thank you~

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/178864/how-to-run-tuckarm-on-hydro?/) by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2570 on 2014-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think the pr2_tuckarm package is released for Hydro yet. Sorry.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/189/sam/) on 2014-06-29**:
What's the main difference between groovy and hydro? Why it couldn't work on hydro? Thank you~

**Comment by [DevonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/4255/devonw/) on 2014-07-13**:
https://github.com/PR2/pr2_apps/tree/hydro-devel/pr2_tuckarm

It is available in source, but It has not been tested ;) Give it a try.